# Is it safe to use thread local in spring mvc app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thread-local

Hello I have a typical app with `@RestController`, which handle requests, a service class, which send requests to a different web app, and a lot of other services, classes and code between them. So, I should send some new information from controller to service and then to that different app, and with the purpose of not changing that tones of code between controller and service I would like to use one ThreadLocal variable, save that new information on it in controller, get it in service and send to third party app. As java servlet should have one thread for one request - there shouldn't be any multi-threading issues, isn't it?

Comment: What would be the issue passing the data via parameters?

Comment: @sp00m there are a lot of classes and methods through which i should pass new parameter

Comment: What about request scoped bean? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes#1-request-scope I think that's better for testing and fits the spring environment better

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt thx, i'll try it

Comment: Good luck. Let me know if it solved your issue.

Comment: I have a new problem, besides spring rest controllers, i have some Kafka handlers in my app, are thread local variable or spring bean with request scope will be unique for each time when i receiving a message at kafka handler?